# Problems understanding dual of $C_b[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces

I know that the dual of $C_b[0,1]$ is the space of finitely additive regular measures. But $C_b[0,1]$ is the same space is $C[0,1]$ and suddenly the dual shrinks to only the $\sigma$-additive measures. Can someone explain this?

Moreover, I have the same problem with $C_b(\mathbb R)$. We have $C_0(\mathbb R)$ contained as a subspace, why should the dual of $C_0$ be smaller then?

Comment: Where did you get that first statement from?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83593/dual-space-of-continuous-functions and https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/dual-spaces-of-continuous-functions/

Comment: Thanks. And it seems the dual of $C[0,1]$ is the space of Radon measures. So I guess we must show the space of finitely additive regular measures is the same as the space of Radon measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your first question, there is a theorem due to Alexandroff, which says that if $X$ is a compact topological space and
 $M$ is an algebra that contains all open sets, then every finitely additive regular measures $\lambda:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is countably additive. Moreover, if $X$ is a Hausdorff space, then $\lambda$ can be extended in a unique
way as a signed Radon measure to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $M$.
You can find this in [Dunford-Schwartz](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471608483.html) or [Fonseca-Leoni](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387357843).

Concerning your second question, if you have a linear continuous functional $L:C_0(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ then you can represent it as $L(f)=\int_\mathbb{R}f\,d\mu$, where $\mu$ is a Radon measure. Since $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in $C_b$ or in the space of bounded functions, by the Hahn-Banach theorem you can extend $L$ to a continuous linear functional defined in those spaces. In turn the extension can be represented as an integral with respect to a finitely additive measure, say $\lambda$. All you know is that $\int_\mathbb{R}f\,d\mu=\int_\mathbb{R}f\,d\lambda$ for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$. The standard example is the   [Banach limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit). The idea is that you can have "nasty" functionals which, when restricted to smaller spaces, are much nicer.

Comment: To the second question: So the extension of $L$ is **not** just integration with respect to $\mu$? This seemed so natural to me because this integral is also well defined that I automatically assumed it was true. This explains a lot. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: No, you can have different measures $\lambda$ which when restricted gives you $\mu$. Banach limits have exactly this property.